# Omnichannel for sales on Dynamics CE 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365-sales

I realize that Omnichannel is currently only associated with the Customer Service module for 365. However we have had a request from a client to provide Omnichannel for a sales process on a web site which links into a sales CE 365 organization (so in other words an agent to guide the user through the sales process via a chat if need be).

Is it possible to add in the Omnichannel module for sales in any way and if not any sort of alternate solutions we could follow for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Omnichannel is built on top of Customer Service so having this first-party app installed is a requirement detailed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/api-limits#service-protection-api-limit-errors-returned). I recommend you to contact your MS Account Manager and discuss this topic with them as depending on your requirements you might also need Power BI/Customer Voice/Power Virtual Agent licenses as well so maybe it's worth to explore some cross-application licensing.

There're alternative solutions in AppSource like [CafeX LiveAssist](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/cafexliveassistfor365.27ac7522-68b2-44a2-9f36-da66a47e2b19?tab=overview) and a few others, please make sure you filter by application to make sure they will work with Sales.

Comment: Many thanks for that answer. Definitely understand where you are coming from. Ok well lets look at it in a different light.. if they have customer service and sales is it possible to use leads in the situation as i know it is purely focused on customers (account/contact) and cases.. i.e. only create a lead in the system and associate it with the conversation instead of above mentioned customer/case

Comment: Glad it helped. No, you can't use leads, as far as I know you can only link conversations to contacts/accounts and cases. The conversation entity can't be customized, so there's not option to create your custom lookup either.